# How to create a customized calendar in MPP VBA and take a work day difference between 2 dates?

Tags: vba, ms-project

Is there way I can duplicate/create a calendar in VBA (or read from MPP calendar) in Microsoft Project and then calculate the work day difference (Duration) using that calendar between 2 dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Project has a function `DateDifference` which takes three arguments: Start date, Finish date, and ***Calendar***. You need to pass it the Calendar object, not the string name of the calendar. The return value is the number of working minutes, so divide by the appropriate amount to get hours, typically 480 (8 hours * 60 minutes).

For example, this gives you the number of working days in December, based on the project calendar.

```
Application.DateDifference("12/1/17","12/31/17", ActiveProject.Calendar) / 480
```

Here's the relevant [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/application-datedifference-method-project) article.

Comment: Got it to work as needed, thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If your calendar is standard (E.G. 5-day working week from Monday to Friday), you could create your own function, like:

```
Function Workdays(Start_Date As Date, End_Date As Date) AS Integer
    Dim Temp_Delta As Integer, X As Integer, Y As Integer
    Temp_Delta = End_Date - Start_Date
    Temp_Delta = 5 * (Temp_Delta \ 7)
    X = Weekday(End_Date, vbMonday)
    Y = Weekday(Start_Date, vbMonday)
    If X > 5 Then X = 5
    If Y > 5 Then Y = 5
    Temp_Delta = Temp_Delta + X - Y
    Workdays = Temp_Delta
End Function
```